# invalid operands of types 'int*' and 'int*' to binary 'operator+'

Tags: c++, pointers

I am experimenting with some basic C++ examples. I am having trouble understanding the reason for the above compilation error. This is the example I am trying.

```
void update(int *a,int *b) {   
    int c = a+b; // Error occurs here
    int d = a-b; // But not here
    int e = a*b; // Error
    int f = a/b; // Error
}

int main(){
    int a = 4, b = 8;
    update(&a, &b);
}
```

I understand that `a-b` case above gives the difference between the two memory addresses as a multiple of the size of an `int`, so `d` will be -1 (update: assuming `a` and `b` are consecutive variables in the memory).

Could someone please explain me what's happening in the other three cases and the meaning of the error.

Comment: You are trying to add pointers. Did you mean to add the values of the `int`s together?

Comment: Those aren't allowed because they make no sense. Imagine you have two int pointers `a` and `b` pointing to a valid place... what's `a+b` supposed to represent? Same goes for `a*b` and `a/b`.

Comment: @ Niroshan The error message is enough clear.

Comment: Hmm, after consideration, this is not a bad question. The answer is "because they don't mean anything", but it's still reasonable.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen why is it still reasonable?

Comment: I also think this is a reasonable beginner question that should be answered. It's not obvious that the compiler would issue errors for such statements.

Comment: @TK-421 IMO, a question "why only operator - is allowed for pointers, while other arithmetic operators result in an error" is a pretty good one. The answer may be obvious to anyone knowing pointer arithemetic, but it's clear and answerable (and may be helpful for others, if there are no duplicates yet). Needs a bit of editing, but it's worth an answer.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I do not see why the question is reasonable. Moreover the question is created by a professional programmer with two years of experience. Does he use for example the operator / for references?

Comment: I'm not sure that `d` is _guaranteed_ to be `-1`. I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: `a` and `b` in `main()` are distinct objects, so the subtraction in `update()`  gives undefined behaviour  (no diagnostic required). The behaviour on subtractng two pointers is only well-defined if both pointers point at parts of the same object (e.g. at elements of the same array or one-past the end of that array, or at members of the same struct, etc). The result of adding two pointers (distinct from adding the values at those two addresses) is meaningless, so gives a compilation error. Similar comment for multiplication and division of pointers.

Comment: @Peter Please no full answers in comments :)

Comment: The purpose of asking this question is consolidating my understanding. Thanks everyone for pitching in!

Comment: Isn't there a requirement that calculating the difference between two pointers that the two pointers are part of the same array, or the bigger pointer is just past the object (so the pointer is valid, but cannot be dereferenced because it is _past_ the end of the object)?  `int a[9]; auto diff = &a[9] - &a[0];` is okay, `int x; auto diff = (&x + 1) - &x;` is okay, but `struct mn_t { int m; int n; } s; auto diff = &n - &m;` is not okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid pointer contains the address of some location in memory. The concept of a pointer variable is built into the language which means the operators that are allowed by default are also built into the language.

The operator minus or subtraction of two pointers has a number of useful applications in programming because it gives you a value of the difference or offset between the two memory locations.

The logical operators for equality as well as greater or lesser also have a number of useful applications in programming.

The question is what utility do other operators such as the plus, multiplication, and division operators may have.

The idea of adding or subtracting an offset to a pointer makes sense as it is a way of being able to iterate over a series of memory locations.

What should the addition of two pointers do? What is the utility of adding two pointers and what should the result be?

If we think of memory as being a line and a pointer is a variable that contains a position along the line then perhaps we can have a mathematical conception for what operators for pointers make sense and have utility and which operators do not.

What we are doing with pointer variable mathematics is a form of translation. When we add or subtract an offset to a pointer, we are translating the location from one place on the line to another.

When we are subtracting pointers, we get an offset that indicates what value we need to add or subtract from either of the pointers to translate one to the other's position.

The logical operators tell us the relationship between two pointers, whether they are the same location on the line or one is greater or lessor than the other.

How does adding two pointers help us with translating pointers or determining the relationship between two points on a line? If a pointer variable contained a vector, a point with a direction, then adding two pointers would make sense because it would be adding two vectors. However pointers are variables that do not contain a vector, there is no direction with a pointer. A pointer contains a value that is a location along a one dimensional line.